# Change Text Colour in LyX

Tags: formatting, color, lyx

I am using LyX (module: report).

I would like to change the colour of my title from black (wich is default) to another colour but I don't know how.

From what I saw from LyX's menu, colours are limited but I want more options. Here's LyX's menu for text colours:

[image]

Probably I must enter some code before my text in order to change colour?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
On preamble :

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.9}
and then i change colour with the command :
\color{Blue}
```

Comment: You should use newer `xcolor` not the older `color` package.

Comment: whats the difference?

Comment: From the manual: "xcolor provides easy driver-independent access to several kinds of colors,
tints, shades, tones, and mixes of arbitrary colors by means of color expres-
sions like \color{red!50!green!20!blue}. It allows to select a document-
wide target color model and offers tools for automatic color schemes, conver-
sion between twelve color models, alternating table row colors, color blending
and masking, color separation, and color wheel calculations." For more see there.

Comment: Where can i find xcolor manual ? Is it possible to put with xcolor shadows on my text ?

Comment: You find all package manuals on CTAN. For xcolor it is http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor. If you are using TeX Live simply use `texdoc xcolor` on the command line.

Comment: How can change the heading of **theorem**,**lemma**, and **definition** to red or blue? many thanks